# lvalue conversion and assignment operator

Tags: c++

Help me understand how assignment operator `=` and implicit (standard) convertion work.

Consider statement `a = b;` where `a` and `b` are lvalues which have different arithmetic types (for example `int a = 1`, `float b = 3.14`).

As I understood, there is no direct "lvalue-to-lvalue" implicit conversion in C++. I think here implicit conversion "lvalue-to-rvalue" takes place: compiler creates a temporary float prvalue (call it `c`) and copies `b` value to `c`. Then our compiler makes "floating-integral conversion": it creates another temporary prvalue (call it `d`) with type int (int is a type of `a`) and converts float `c` to int `b`. Now temporary prvalue `d` has int value `3`. Finally the compiler copies `d` value to variable `a` and we get `a = 3`.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/g/LJHCYF) is what the latest gcc does.

Comment: NathanOliver, thanks for your link. It seems that I was right. If we denote `c` by `xmm0` and `d` by `eax` we will get the situation I described above.